# Open Graph: post of a custom action on a custom object, the feed doesn't contains link/ or URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm new to FB open graph. I created a custom action (advice) and a custom object (activity). 
I created my own story: SOMEONE "advice" an "activity" on "MyApp".
It works, but I'd like to have in the post on facebook also a link that is referred to this activity...I can't do it and it's going my head in!
I added this meta data property in the HTML document for the object activity:
"property="og:see_also" content="http://something.it/""
I tried added it to the attachments using this way: typing something like {activity.see_also} in the textarea that is showed in the setting of the story (Edit Attachments section)
This is the preview after I modified the attachments options for the story:
http://qkingprove.altervista.org/screenshot/Schermata.png
but this is the result after I posted the action in my timeline:
http://qkingprove.altervista.org/screenshot/Schermata-1.png